# How to implement third-party impressions tracking URL from Sizmek?

Tags: javascript, html, tracking, banner, impressions

I've received 2 third-party tracking links for an Expanding banner ad. One of them is for Click Tracking and another is for Imps tracking. I've never been requested to implement both, as the platform that we use (OAS) tracks Imps and Clicks. There is no field to insert Imps tracking link, and from my understanding I would need to create additional code to support third-party imps tracking. I've researched internet but can't find any useful information on this issue, aside that other people are struggling with the same problem. Here is the imps tracking URL I was provided:

//To track Impressions use the following URL:
http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&c=19&mc=imp&pli=16649639&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]&rtu=-1

Please let me know if somebody was able to successfully implement the third-party tracking imps link, and what it takes to build the supporting code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was simple. All I had to do was to add following html at the end of the creative tag:

```
<img src="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&c=19&mc=imp&pli=16649639&PluID=0&ord=12345&rtu=-1" border="0" width="1" height="1" />
```

This creates a pixel image that shows up when banner loads and allows third-party track impression with the link they've provided.

Answer (score -2):

Implement the code near to the creative in the following format:

```
<IMG SRC="Impression_Tracker_URL" BORDER=0  WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 ALT=”Advertisement” style=”display:none;">
```

For script tracker you can directly implement it as it is. Example:

```
<script src="TRACKER_URL.JS" type="text/javascript"></script>
```