# How to implement third-party impression and click tags from Sizmek in html email?

Tags: html, tags, tracking

I need to use click and impression trackers in a newsletter (html format).
This is what I have received:

> //To track Impressions use the following URL:
>   https://bs.serving-sys.com/serving/adServer.bs?cn=display&c=19&mc=imp&pli=23041536&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]&rtu=-1
>   //To track Clicks use the following URL: //Note: Please ensure that
>   you implement a click tracking URL only in the clicks location in your
>   ad server,  //and an impression tracking URL only in the impression
>   tracking location. //Client is solely responsible for, and Sizmek has
>   no liability for, any failure to properly implement the URLs and any
>   related billing and reporting discrepancies.
>   https://bs.serving-sys.com/serving/adServer.bs?cn=trd&mc=click&pli=23041536&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]

1/ For the click tracker do I need to change anything in the URL? I couldn't find if this needs to be changed and if yes with what: [timestamp]

2/ For the impression tracker I have added this code:

```
<p><img src="https://bs.serving-sys.com/serving/adServer.bs?cn=display&c=19&mc=imp&pli=23041536&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]&rtu=-1"border="0" width="1" height="1"/></p>
```

But I get an error when I inspect the email received in my Gmail inbox. And the impressions are not recorded in reports. Do I need to make sure Gmail image proxy can fetch the image from google server? Can my dev team do that or who provided the tags should do that?
My scr changes to 
https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/3Kqxq0F1-wHLxzoSM4lRZHNmE27pdJI_yyiLW4uYKgq1Tq7W9hJSOzjFwe8soNSohQ11OjEW2wvuRJHZUB7NTW7szdk7-3y-1AeY5ZqqFXtmgdN8orItBF98YIgZ3NLdordshaBg60EOfqfmbeX-R6cVZMaYIGICruFOPfuHj_6BGAxfdzEW=s0-d-e1-ft#https://bs.serving-sys.com/serving/adServer.bs?cn=display&c=19&mc=imp&pli=23041536&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]&rtu=-1

Found this documentation but it is not very clear yet.

- [How to implement third-party impressions tracking URL from Sizmek?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994709/how-to-implement-third-party-impressions-tracking-url-from-sizmek)
- [Image links broken in Gmail because of google's Image proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491590/image-links-broken-in-gmail-because-of-googles-image-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to change anything in the click tracker URL. You only need to copy the entire URL `https://bs.serving-sys.com/serving/adServer.bs?cn=trd&mc=click&pli=23041536&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]`and insert it in Ad Server as a click target URL to secure counting of clicks on Sizmek system side. You should not add any JS code / HTML elements to your email template for the click tracking.
2. Alternatively you can try to create a 1x1 pixel impression counter dynamically like

```
var  impCounter = new Image (1,1);
impCounter.src=": https://bs.serving-sys.com/serving/adServer.bs?cn=display&c=19&mc=imp&pli=23041536&PluID=0&ord=[timestamp]&rtu=-1";
```